# Cannot get header that contains a period from NGINX

Tags: nginx, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, header, aspnetboilerplate

The header `"Abp.TenantId"` is `null` because of the `"."`.

If remove the `"."` (like `"AbpTenantId"`), it will be ok.

**How to add a header with a `"."`?**

=======================================================

`localhost` debug:

1. Provisional headers are shown (show this on client request)
2. Request.Headers.Unknown (show this in server, api action)
3. Request.Headers.MaybeUnknown (show this in server, api action)

`localhost` is ok.

The same code in server, but server error.

The code for the `tenantId`:

[image]

The logs have no `tenantId`, so error:

[image]

`localhost` is ok:

[image: localhost success]

Server fail:

[image: server fail]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nginx as a reverse proxy will not pass headers that contain a period.](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/629)

## ABP 4.4+

`TenantIdResolveKey` is configurable:

```cs
Configuration.MultiTenancy.TenantIdResolveKey = "Abp-TenantId";
```

## Below ABP 4.4

You can turn off [ignore "invalid" headers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#ignore_invalid_headers) in Nginx:

> ```
> Syntax:  ignore_invalid_headers on | off;
> Default: ignore_invalid_headers on;
> Context: http, server
> ```
>
> Controls whether header fields with invalid names should be ignored. Valid names are composed of English letters, digits, hyphens, and possibly underscores (as controlled by the underscores_in_headers directive).
>
> If the directive is specified on the server level, its value is only used if a server is a default one. The value specified also applies to all virtual servers listening on the same address and port.