# AbpUserRequestCultureProvider returned the following unsupported cultures

Tags: c#, asp.net, culture, aspnetboilerplate

When I check my logs on my Angular ASP.NET application, I'm repeatedly getting this error message:

`WARN  2018-07-19 05:43:09,596 [42   ] calization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware - AbpUserRequestCultureProvider returned the following unsupported cultures 'null'.
WARN  2018-07-19 05:43:09,596 [42   ] calization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware - AbpUserRequestCultureProvider returned the following unsupported UI Cultures 'null'.
WARN  2018-07-19 05:43:09,596 [42   ] calization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware - AbpLocalizationHeaderRequestCultureProvider returned the following unsupported cultures 'null'`

Has anyone had any experience with this, or what could be causing the issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It means ABP couldn't get user's language from header of the request. 
Normally it checks the header `.AspNetCore.Culture` and returns null if not found. 
Check your request headers...

A sample header value is below;

```
.AspNetCore.Culture=c=en|uic=en
```

- c:Culture
- uic: Ui Culture

Answer (score 0):

I'm failure with header: `.AspNetCore.Culture`,
This one works on my project: header: `Accept-Language` value: "en-US".

Comment: Hi Akira, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`'null'` culture issue was fixed in [Prevent null being saved into user's DefaultLanguage](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/4823) (ABP 4.9, Sep 2019).

Another issue is that [Nginx as a reverse proxy will not pass headers that contain a period.](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/629)

In this case, the `".AspNetCore.Culture"` header.

Related: [Cannot get header that contains a period from NGINX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49801326/8601760) for the `"Abp.TenantId"` header (ABP 4.4, Mar 2019).

## ABP 6.0+

`AbpLocalizationHeaderRequestCultureProvider.HeaderName` is configurable.

1. In [Startup.cs#L132](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/1be7ee114725359002ea4b70377b331a7529cc52/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Host/Startup/Startup.cs#L132), get `AbpLocalizationHeaderRequestCultureProvider` and set its `HeaderName`:

```cs
// app.UseAbpRequestLocalization();
   app.UseAbpRequestLocalization(options =>
   {
       var headerProvider = options.RequestCultureProviders.OfType<AbpLocalizationHeaderRequestCultureProvider>().First();
       headerProvider.HeaderName = "AspNetCore-Culture";
   });
```

2. In [app-initializer.ts#L122](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/8dc59e36fe8e07e318f55527a35baa40ad07f010/angular/src/app-initializer.ts#L122), replace `'.AspNetCore.Culture'` with `'AspNetCore-Culture'`:

```
// '.AspNetCore.Culture': `c=${cookieLangValue}|uic=${cookieLangValue}`,
    'AspNetCore-Culture': `c=${cookieLangValue}|uic=${cookieLangValue}`,
```

## Below ABP 6.0

1. Copy `AbpLocalizationHeaderRequestCultureProvider` with the patch to your project as `MyLocalizationHeaderRequestCultureProvider`.
2. In [Startup.cs#L132](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/1be7ee114725359002ea4b70377b331a7529cc52/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Host/Startup/Startup.cs#L132), insert an instance of `MyLocalizationHeaderRequestCultureProvider` into `RequestCultureProviders` after setting its `HeaderName`.

```cs
// app.UseAbpRequestLocalization();
   app.UseAbpRequestLocalization(options =>
   {
       var headerProvider = new MyLocalizationHeaderRequestCultureProvider();
       headerProvider.HeaderName = "AspNetCore-Culture";
       options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(2, headerProvider);
   });
```

3. In [app-initializer.ts#L122](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/8dc59e36fe8e07e318f55527a35baa40ad07f010/angular/src/app-initializer.ts#L122), replace `'.AspNetCore.Culture'` with `'AspNetCore-Culture'`.

### Alternative

You can turn off [ignore "invalid" headers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#ignore_invalid_headers) in Nginx.